# PuTTY Syntax for copying linux disk to Windows drive directory

Tags: server, ssh, dd

I am trying to get PuTTy to copy a linode disk to an .img file on a windows pc. I am logging into the linode server as administrator and it shows up as 'root' in the PuTTy window. I ran this command: (from "ssh forward)

```
root@2:~# ssh root@172.105.254.215 "dd if=/dev/sda " | dd of=C:\Linode\linode.img
```

I entered the correct password as requested

```
root@172.105.254.215's password:
```

I then received the following message:

```
dd: writing to 'C:Linodelinode.img': No space left on device
1988161+0 records in
1988160+0 records out
1017937920 bytes (1.0 GB, 971 MiB) copied, 57.4166 s, 17.7 MB/s
```

The source disk is only 50gb.  The destination disk has 77.1GB free.
The directory `C:\Linode` does exist and there is no file by that name in the directory.

Comment: What's the flow here? You SSH from Windows using Putty to some system A (whose prompt begins with `root@2`) and then SSH from there to another system B (with IP `172.105.254.215`)? If that's the case, you just wrote the output file to system A, not to your Windows directory.

Comment: Yes I am running ssh from windows using putty to a linode 0n 172.105.254.215.     
  Then dd uses the standard context of if=/dev/sda " which means the source file and the output file  is: of=C:\Linode\linode.img.   I am sure this is the correct syntax; but if you can point out the correct syntax I'll try it.

Comment: Then in which system do you see the `root@2` prompt?

Comment: root@2 is the ubuntu server

Comment: I've since had it confirmed by Linode, it is not possible to dd from a linux instance to a windows partition.

Any other options?